# Why does Logistic Regression output show Z-test whereas Linear regression show T-test in the ouput?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, regression-coefficients, standard-error, t-distribution

Why does Logistic Regression output show Z-test whereas Linear regression shows the t-test in the ouput?
Why logistic regression prefers Z-test when the same can be achieved with the help of t-test?
Also suggest me if there is something I can read about this.